# How do I replace resource file in foreign .APK?

Tags: android, apk, signing, rebuild

today I tried to replace default sounds for the TickTick app with custom ones, but I failed miserably. I tried apktool to decompile the app, replace the sound files in resources, compile it back, but this is the end for me, because apktool doesn't work with my setup (Ubuntu 21.10), not even if I run `apktool d base.apk`; then immediately `apktool d base`. It just crashes with [this error](https://pastebin.com/phydWtFX).
So I tried directly modifying .apk file, replacing sounds, zipaligning result and signing the app (tried apksigner, jarsigner); also tried deleting whole META-INF, not deleting it, deleting only .SF, .RSA files.
When I use the combination of not deleting META-INF, modifying the sound files, zipaligning/not zipaligning before signing, then signing the app it **can** be installed, but when I try to run it, only black screen gets displayed.
Logcat gives me below information.

```
04-15 19:09:29.442 E/AndroidRuntime(26166):     at com.ticktick.task.TickTickApplicationBase.initKernelManager(TickTickApplicationBase.java:2)
04-15 19:09:29.442 E/AndroidRuntime(26166):     at com.ticktick.task.TickTickApplicationBase.onCreate(TickTickApplicationBase.java:19)
04-15 19:09:29.442 E/AndroidRuntime(26166):     at com.ticktick.task.TickTickApplication.onCreate(TickTickApplication.java:1)
```

Since I cannot turn on debug mode, because apktool doesn't work for me I am lost. Is there anyone with more knowledge on this subject than me, who would be willing to help?
Thanks for reading this far.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out apktool currently has a [bug](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2756), so once I used workaround from user Gourov, I was able to use apktool. I encountered another problem however - APK exported from my mobile **wouldn't start** once altered, so I went to apkmirror.com to retrieve APK for the app, decoded it using apktool, replaced audio files with mine, built it using apktool, signed it with apksigner, installed it on my phone using adb install and it just works :)